# Google Charts Table: setting border around entire table, but not individual elements

Tags: php, css, json, google-visualization

I have been able to use the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table) to set the border thickness of each cell of the table using 'tableCell' with CSS (via "cssClassNames"). However I cannot figure out how to make a border around the entire table without effecting the individual cells.

I am not sure if this supported, if someone knows how to do this please let me know.

I am using JSON with PHP to generate my data in case that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a border on the table's container div in CSS:

```
#myTableDiv {
    border: 2px solid #8367d9;
}
```

**[edit]**

If you set the dimensions of the Table in the Visualization's options, you either need to use a more specific selector in the css:

```
#myTableDiv > div > div {
    border: 2px solid #8367d9;
}
```

or you need to set the container div to display as an inline-block:

```
#myTableDiv {
    border: 2px solid #8367d9;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I would recommend going with the second approach if it is viable in your case, as the first needs refining to make it work when you have a scrollable table.

Comment: I tried that and there is a border now, but its much bigger than the physical table size. I am using "width:500,height:300" in the options when I call chart.draw() and the chart itself reflects these dimensions, but for some reason the table's container big is bigger than this - it fits the entire horizontal width of the page. Any ideas how to synchronize these?

Comment: Unless you set the width of a div in CSS, it is always takes up as much width as it can.  When you set the dimensions of the table in the options, they get set on a grandchild div of the container div, so you either need to use `#myTableDiv > div > div` as the selector, or you need to set the container div's `display` property to `inline-block`.  I'll update the answer with details.

Comment: Thanks, "inline-block" does it!